# Windows Tablet with no pen lag

Tags: tablet

I'm currently looking to buy a new Windows tablet for drawing. The problem is that I couldn't find an affordable tablet without any pen lag. The only tablets I know that have low lattency when drawings are the iPad 6 and iPad Pro. Are they any affordable windows tablet that has no significant pen lag ?

Comment: Personally, the people that I know of that engage in graphic design typically use and recommend [drawing pen tablets like these](https://www.amazon.com/Wacom-Bamboo-Capture-Tablet-CTH470/dp/B005HGBEZ2) rather than consumer touchscreens, particularly due to the fact touchscreens do not have good (if at all) pressure sensitivity. These drawing pen tablets do not seem to have any lag. I am also not an artist and cannot speak to the durability or usability of these drawing pen tablets.

Comment: Hi @BennettYeo, Your comment is very useful.  Very.  I believe it would qualify as a full answer.  If you don't mind, please add this info as an answer so I can upvote it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, the people that I know of that engage in graphic design typically use and recommend [**drawing pen tablets**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HGBEZ2) like these rather than consumer touchscreens, particularly due to the fact touchscreens do not have good (if at all) pressure sensitivity. These drawing pen tablets do not seem to have any lag.

There are also [**specialized drawing tablets**, on which you can draw directly on](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077PCCC7R), however; they tend to be very pricey compared to cheaper "dumb" input pen tablets (like the wacom drawing tablet specified in the link above) that I see most beginners start with.

I am also not an artist and cannot speak to the durability or usability of these drawing pen tablets. As a result I am not comfortable directly recommending a specific tablet because I cannot speak to its efficacy. I hope this answer is ultimately able to help narrow down your hardware choices.

---

Useful link on [Article covering best Drawing Tablets](https://www.thearchitectsguide.com/blog/best-drawing-tablets).

Comment: And as always if someone is able to provide a better, more specific answer to our OP's question you are free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The tablet I can propose is Microsoft Surface 4. Specially model with 8GB of RAM and i5 processor have no problem with latency and I use it extensively with Adobe Lightroom with pen. Also time to time I play with Windows 10 app for handwriting and see no lag of pen.